# How to compute a 30-minute time average across an hour using xarray

Tags: python, python-xarray, weather

Hello to the Stack OverFlow Community,

I am struggling to create a clear method to average timeseries data using xarray in 30-minute intervals, when the averaging interval crosses the top of a particular hour. Specifically, I am trying to average the timeseries data within a window that begins 15-minutes before the top of the hour (e.g. 12:45PM) and ends 15-minutes after the top of the hour (e.g. 1:15PM).

Here is a dummy xarray DataArray that is nearly the same format as the actual timeseries data I am working with:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr

#Define random data and associated times for data
time        = pd.date_range(start='2022-05-11 00:00:00', end='2022-05-11 23:15:00', freq='2min')
random_data = np.random.randint(100, size=len(time))

#Create xarray DataArray to hold dummy data
data_array = xr.DataArray(data=random_data, coords={'time':time})
```

I have been browsing through some of the [intermediate level xarray documentation](https://tutorial.xarray.dev/intermediate/01-high-level-computation-patterns) and have tried one (failed) method to achieve my desired time averaging scheme which involves using the xarray.DataArray `"groupby_bins"` method:

```
#Manually define the bins we want to use for time averaging
time_averaging_bins = pd.date_range(start='2022-05-11 00:45:00', end='2022-05-11 23:15:00', freq='30min')

#Group our DataArray by these bins
data_array_binned = data_array.groupby_bins(group='time', bins=time_averaging_bins, right=True)

#View the results for the first few groups (using a clunky "for" loop method)
for index, group in enumerate(data_array_binned):
    if index < 4:
        print(group)
        print(' ')

**OUTPUT:**

(Interval('2022-05-11 00:45:00', '2022-05-11 01:15:00', closed='right'), <xarray.DataArray (time: 15)>
array([31., 17., 87., 87.,  4.,  4.,  2., 30., 32., 18., 80., 85., 48.,
       38., 94.])
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2022-05-11T00:46:00 ... 2022-05-11T01:14:00)
 
(Interval('2022-05-11 01:15:00', '2022-05-11 01:45:00', closed='right'), <xarray.DataArray (time: 15)>
array([79.,  3., 37., 38., 83., 48., 21., 85., 38., 83., 52., 15., 34.,
       29.,  8.])
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2022-05-11T01:16:00 ... 2022-05-11T01:44:00)
 
(Interval('2022-05-11 01:45:00', '2022-05-11 02:15:00', closed='right'), <xarray.DataArray (time: 15)>
array([42., 66., 47., 63., 44., 66., 96., 57., 57., 92., 10., 73., 47.,
       29., 79.])
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2022-05-11T01:46:00 ... 2022-05-11T02:14:00)
 
(Interval('2022-05-11 02:15:00', '2022-05-11 02:45:00', closed='right'), <xarray.DataArray (time: 15)>
array([16., 89., 64., 85., 94., 80., 75.,  2., 98., 10., 62., 89., 85.,
       12., 18.])
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2022-05-11T02:16:00 ... 2022-05-11T02:44:00)
```

This method nearly gets me to where I want, since every other bin contains the group of timeseries values I am interested in (i.e. the values that occur within the averaging window defined as 15-min before and 15-min after the top of the hour). One solution to this would be to use this binning method and index the averaged array to grab every other value. This seems a bit clunky and error-prone, which is why I am pursuing a more elegant solution. I tried researching if it was possible to skip every other bin when initially using the "groupby_bins" methods, but to no avail.

Another method I tried was using the "dt" accessor for the time dimension/coordinate, but was unable to figure out a way to code my desired averaging window using boolean logic and hour integers that change. Here is an example for a single bin:

```
data_array_grouped = data_array.groupby(((data_array.time.dt.hour == 0) & (data_array.time.dt.minute > 45)) | ((data_array.time.dt.hour == 0+1) & (data_array.time.dt.minute <= 15)))
```

This option would work nicely if I could figure out how to replace `data_array.time.dt.hour == 0` and `data_array.time.dt.hour == 1` with values that iterate as the averaging window moves through each hour. Perhaps a "for" loop would allow for this, but, if possible, I would like to implement something a bit easier to read and reproduce with other timeseries data in the future.

Apologies for the lengthy question. Any guidance is greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time and attention.

Best,

Marian

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution which still requires some arbitrary indexing (which declines readability and reproducibility):

```
#Create a time index which loosely fits our time-averaging criteria
time_index = (data_array.time.dt.minute >= 45) | (data_array.time.dt.minute < 15)

#Index our DataArray with this time index
data_array_time_indexed = data_array[time_index]

#View a few of the time values that are included in this newly indexed DataArray
print(data_array_time_indexed.time.values[0:23])
```

```
**OUTPUT**

['2022-05-11T00:00:00.000000000' '2022-05-11T00:02:00.000000000'
 '2022-05-11T00:04:00.000000000' '2022-05-11T00:06:00.000000000'
 '2022-05-11T00:08:00.000000000' '2022-05-11T00:10:00.000000000'
 '2022-05-11T00:12:00.000000000' '2022-05-11T00:14:00.000000000'
 '2022-05-11T00:46:00.000000000' '2022-05-11T00:48:00.000000000'
 '2022-05-11T00:50:00.000000000' '2022-05-11T00:52:00.000000000'
 '2022-05-11T00:54:00.000000000' '2022-05-11T00:56:00.000000000'
 '2022-05-11T00:58:00.000000000' '2022-05-11T01:00:00.000000000'
 '2022-05-11T01:02:00.000000000' '2022-05-11T01:04:00.000000000'
 '2022-05-11T01:06:00.000000000' '2022-05-11T01:08:00.000000000'
 '2022-05-11T01:10:00.000000000' '2022-05-11T01:12:00.000000000'
 '2022-05-11T01:14:00.000000000']
```

```
#We see that our desired averaging window can be found if 
#we drop the first 8 values of the time indexed DataArray and 
#then use the xarray "coarsen" and "mean" methods to group and average data.

#Drop first 8 values by indexing the time-indexed DataArray from 9th index
#position to the end of the array (this method, in my opinion, hurts code readability)
data_array_time_indexed_dropped = data_array_time_indexed[8::]

#View a few time steps now
print(data_array_time_indexed_dropped.time.values[0:15])
```

```
**OUTPUT** (OUR DESIRED AVERAGING WINDOW FOR A SINGLE AVERAGING TIME)

['2022-05-11T00:46:00.000000000' '2022-05-11T00:48:00.000000000'
 '2022-05-11T00:50:00.000000000' '2022-05-11T00:52:00.000000000'
 '2022-05-11T00:54:00.000000000' '2022-05-11T00:56:00.000000000'
 '2022-05-11T00:58:00.000000000' '2022-05-11T01:00:00.000000000'
 '2022-05-11T01:02:00.000000000' '2022-05-11T01:04:00.000000000'
 '2022-05-11T01:06:00.000000000' '2022-05-11T01:08:00.000000000'
 '2022-05-11T01:10:00.000000000' '2022-05-11T01:12:00.000000000'
 '2022-05-11T01:14:00.000000000']
```

```
#Coarsen this new DataArray every 15 time points and take the mean. 
#The number for coarsening will change depending on the time resolution of the data, 
#and thus one would need to perform these manual inspections for every new dataset. 
#One positive thing about the coarsen method is that the "time" coordinate will be averaged as well, which makes life a bit easier.
data_array_time_indexed_dropped_coarsened = data_array_time_indexed_dropped.coarsen(time=15, boundary='exact', side='left', coord_func='mean')

#Take average of coarsened DataArray
data_array_time_indexed_dropped_coarsened_averaged = data_array_time_indexed_dropped_coarsened.mean()

#If the user wants to get a better sense of 
#how each group is constructed, run the following:
data_array_time_indexed_dropped_coarsened.construct(time=('bin_number', 'bin_values'))
```

I will leave this question open in the hopes that someone might offer a solution that can be more universally applied to a range of situations.